# Jssor slider - arrows overlapping images on mobile

Tags: jssor

I integrated the Jssor Image Gallery with Vertical Thumbnails on my WordPress site. The arrows appear as desired on desktop, but the left arrow overlaps the image on mobile display. See below images. Any advice?

[Overlapping on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDT7E.png)

[Appears as desired on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCijr.png)

Comment: open layout window, switch to `arrrows` tab, set `Scale Pos.` option to `1`.